# Set boolean argument as the opposite of another boolean?

Tags: java, boolean

This is kind of hard to phrase.

I have a method (let's call it `method1`) that takes a boolean as argument. It calls another method (`method2`), which also takes a boolean as argument.

I would like method1 to call `method2(true)` if its argument is `false`, and `method2(false)` if its argument is `true`.

I know I could use a simple `if(){...}else{...}`, but is there a way to set a boolean to the opposite of another boolean? Something like this:

`boolean b2=!b1`;

So I could code my methods like this:

```
public void method1(boolean c){
   this.method2(!c);
}
```

Comment: You answered your own question. That's it.

Comment: Yes I did. The first answer was posted while I was editing the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
method1(boolean blah) { 
    method2(!blah); 
}
```

The ! negates the boolean value.